# Running Keras Sequential model in tf session

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Given a Keras sequential model (specifically a 2 layer LSTM): How do we run it in a tf session?

I have to train the model multiple times in a single script and I run out of memory pretty fast. Is running it in a tf session the right solution? If not, what is?

Answer (score 0):

In keras, model.fit() or model.fit_generator() are usually used for model training. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py). If you don't need to stick with tf session, pure keras implementation is also a good choice.

For the out of memory issue, there may be multiple potential reasons. Maybe you can check if your dataset is too large? Without further info about your code, it's hard to say.